# How to create Wake-on-LAN app using Magic packet and Indy in Delphi XE6?

Tags: delphi, networking, ethernet, wake-on-lan

### Environment

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

IDE: Delphi XE6 + Update 1

---

### Goal

Create an application in Delphi XE6 sending [Magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) through Indy components in order to achieve Wake-on-LAN a local server. Server has been tested to be able to wake from a Linux client.

Note, that I want to create my own solution, no application suggestions, please. Thank you.

---

### Magic packet

Quoting part of [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet):

> The magic packet is a broadcast frame containing anywhere within its payload 6 bytes of all 255 (FF FF FF FF FF FF in hexadecimal), followed by sixteen repetitions of the target computer's 48-bit MAC address, for a total of 102 bytes.

---

### Base version

I got the base version from [this page](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=47578).

The author does not mention which version of Delphi he used, let's just suppose an older one.

I will quote it, in case the page becomes unavailable, unaltered:

```
procedure WakeOnLan(const AMacAddress : string);
type
     TMacAddress = array [1..6] of byte;

     TWakeRecord = packed record
       Waker : TMACAddress;
       MAC   : array[0..15] of TMACAddress;
     end;

var i : integer;
    WR : TWakeRecord;
    MacAddress : TMacAddress;
    UDP : TIdUDPClient;
    sData : string;
begin
  // Convert MAC string into MAC array
  fillchar(MacAddress,SizeOf(TMacAddress),0);
  sData := trim(AMacAddress);

  if length(sData) = 17 then begin
    for i := 1 to 6 do begin
      MacAddress[i] := StrToIntDef('$' + copy(sData,1,2),0);
      sData := copy(sData,4,17);
    end;
  end;

  for i := 1 To 6 do WR.Waker[i] := $FF;
  for i := 0 to 15 do WR.MAC[i] := MacAddress;
  // Create UDP and Broadcast data structure
  UDP := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  UDP.Host := '255.255.255.255';
  UDP.Port := 32767;
  UDP.BroadCastEnabled := true;
  UDP.SendBuffer(WR,SizeOf(TWakeRecord));
  UDP.BroadcastEnabled := false;
  UDP.Free;
end;
```

---

But the compiler of Delphi XE6 complains on line:

> ```
> UDP.SendBuffer(WR,SizeOf(TWakeRecord));
> ```

where it says:

> ```
> [dcc64 Error] main.pas(73): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'SendBuffer' that can be called with these arguments
> ```

---

### My version

Re-written the above code for better readability + I have tried various approaches which won't compile ending with this one, which does compile, though it obviously does not work (does not wake the server).

```
procedure WakeOnLan(const AMacAddress: string);

type
  TMacAddress = array [1..6] of Byte;

  TWakeRecord = packed record
    Waker : TMACAddress;
    MAC   : array [0..15] of TMacAddress;
  end;

var
  I          : Integer;
  WR         : TWakeRecord;
  MacAddress : TMacAddress;
  UDPClient  : TIdUDPClient;
  sData      : string;

begin
  FillChar(MacAddress, SizeOf(TMacAddress), 0);

  sData := Trim(AMacAddress);

  if Length(sData) = 17 then begin

    for I := 1 to 6 do begin
      MacAddress[I] := StrToIntDef('$' + Copy(sData, 1, 2), 0);
      sData := Copy(sData, 4, 17);
    end;

  end;

  for I := 1 to 6  do WR.Waker[I] := $FF;
  for I := 0 to 15 do WR.MAC[I]   := MacAddress;

  UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  try

//    UDP.Host := '255.255.255.255';
//    UDP.Port := 32767;

    UDPClient.BroadCastEnabled := True;
    UDPClient.Broadcast(RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(TWakeRecord)), 7);

//    UDP.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(TWakeRecord)));

  UDPClient.BroadcastEnabled := False;
  finally
    UDPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

### EDIT1

I don't want to use any IP addresses at all, just pure MAC address should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code was written for Indy 9.  The Indy 10 equivalent would look more like this:

```
UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
try
  UDP.Host := '255.255.255.255';
  UDP.Port := 32767;
  UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  UDP.BroadcastEnabled := True;
  UDP.SendBuffer(RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(WR)));
finally
  UDP.Free;
end;
```

Or:

```
UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
try
  UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  UDP.BroadCastEnabled := True;
  UDP.SendBuffer('255.255.255.255', 32767, RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(WR)));
finally
  UDP.Free;
end;
```

Or:

```
UDP := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
try
  UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  UDP.Broadcast(RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(WR)), 32767);
finally
  UDP.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, look at the parameters of the SendBuffer function (server, port, buffer):

```
UDP.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
UDP.BroadCastEnabled := True;
UDP.SendBuffer('192.168.1.255', 9, RawToBytes(WR, SizeOf(WR)));
UDP.BroadCastEnabled := False;
```

Note that the broadcast address '255.255.255.255' may not work, you should limit the range of the broadcast as the example.

Comment: You don't need BroadcastEnabled since you are not using the multicast address.

Comment: This might work, although I see I need to clarify I don't want to use any IP addresses at all, just pure MAC address should do.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz assuming the subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`, then `192.168.1.255` is a broadcast address, just one that is limited to the subnet, so `BroadcastEnabled=True` is still needed. The socket's `SO_BROADCAST` option must be enabled when sending to ANY broadcast address. Multicast and Broadcast are two separate things.

Comment: @Remy - That's ok but this code works without setting BroadcastEnabled, with XE2 at least. I read the [docs](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdUDPBase_Broadcast@string@integer.html) before commenting and as far as I understood BroadcastEnabled is only necessary for the zero network broadcast/multicast address.

Comment: I referred 255.255.255.255 as multicast address because of Indy documentation linked in my previous comment: *"...  reserved Multicast network address '255.255.255.255 ..."* It may very well be wrong...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I assure you, `BroadcastEnabled=true` is ALWAYS needed when broadcasting over UDP. Whether it "works" for you is moot, enabling the socket's `SO_BROADCAST` option is an OS requirement on most platforms. Note that `TIdUDPClient` has a `Broadcast()` method that enables `SO_BROADCAST` for you.